# jinja2 if statement not working

Tags: python, if-statement, jinja2

I have a jinja2 `if` statement where I am checking to see if the dictionary item is equal to an id however it never seems to evaluate it correctly or at all.

Here is my `if` statement:

```
<select id="deviceTypes" class="inputBoxes" style="height: 25px;">
    {% for key, value in deviceTypes.iteritems() %}
        {% if deviceTypeID == key %}  --> deviceTypeID is defined but this block of code never runs (key is an integer value, it's the id of the option)
            <option value="{{key}}" selected>{{deviceTypeID}}</option>
        {% else %}
            <option value="{{key}}">{{value}}</option>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Comment: Are you **100% certain** that `deviceTypeID in deviceTypes` is True? Sounds like `deviceTypeID` *is a string*, not an integer, here.

Comment: Where is `deviceTypeID` sourced from?

Comment: deviceTypeID is returned from my python method. because when I select a deviceType, I send the id to the python method, then I return the id with the method for later use. The key in my dictionary is a number just like deviceTypeID

Comment: @MartijnPieters you seem to be correct my good sir...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely your `deviceTypeID` is taken from the request and *still a string*. Make sure it is an integer:

```
{% if deviceTypeID|int == key %}
```

or better still, turn it into an integer when you get it from the request. Many web frameworks let you turn a value into an integer when retrieving it; Flask lets you do:

```
deviceTypeID = request.form.get('deviceTypeID', type=int)
```

for example.

Comment: Hum.. nice feature of Flask. Do you know if it is possible in webapp2 also?

Comment: @infostacker: `webapp2` has [`request.get_range()`](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2.html#webapp2.Request.get_range) which returns an integer within a given range; but the boundaries are optional. `request.get_range('deviceTypeID')` returns an integer value, if possible.

Comment: thanks... don't really understand why they would require a range instead of just do like Flask and let it 'free', but it is good to know anyway

Comment: @infostacker: it's somewhat awkwardly worded, mostly.

Comment: they actually require a range... https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/requestclass#Request_get_range

Comment: @infostacker: the keyword arguments have defaults, so they are optional. I'll check the source code, but the documentation does not suggest that they are required.

Comment: True. I think you are right. I missed the 'if any'. I guess in the end it actually is the same. But definitely the source would help

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to add 'not' to the check? This will tell you if the condition is `false` or not.

{% if not deviceTypeID == key %}

The answer:

```
{% if not deviceTypeID == key %}
    <option value="{{key}}">{{value}}</option>
{% else %}   
    <option value="{{key}}" selected>{{deviceTypeID}}</option>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: apparently my deviceTypeID and key wasn't of the same type(casting wise) hence why it didn't work lol. I just had to cast my key to the same type